# How do I to get id of an enum value with @DropDownListFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created an Enum and the values has id now I need to get the id in @Html.DropDownListFor but I don't know how to do it.

How could I get the id of Enum ?

**Enum**

```
public enum GainLosses
{
    Gain = 1,
    Loss = 2
};
```

**Model**

```
//Gain/Loss
    [DisplayName("Gain/Loss")]
    public int gainLoss { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> gainLosses
    {
        get { return CustomEnum.Enum.GetItems<GainLosses>().Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x.ToString() }); }
    }
    //
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="@Html.IdFor(model => model.gainLoss)" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Gain/Loss <img src="~/Imagens/required.png" height="6" width="6" title="requerido"></label>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.gainLoss, Model.gainLosses, new { Class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.gainLoss, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })                        
                    </div><!--/Gain/Loss-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I've already solved the problem.

```
[DisplayName("Gain/Loss")]
    public int gainLoss { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> gainLosses
    {
        get { return CustomEnum.Enum.GetItems<GainLosses>().Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() }); }
    }
    //
```